# remove some data from json arry

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

This is my json array. this create when I select some elements in drop down list.then no.of array elements can be change

```
"Actions":[  
      {  
         "key":"AC_001",
         "tag":"AWARD_POINTS",
         "name":"Award Points",
         "content":{  
            "html":"<div class='col-sm-4'><label for='point-amount'>Amount</label><input type='number' class='form-control' id='point-amount' placeholder='Add Points'></div>",
            "actions":""
         },
         "identify":"",
         "value":"",
         "uuid":"f0a8ae1f-9c2c-9cc3-eb38-7a7ab0570dd1"
      },
      {  
         "key":"AC_003",
         "tag":"SEND_MAIL",
         "name":"Send Mail",
         "content":{  
            "html":""
         },
         "identify":"",
         "value":"",
         "uuid":"83af6438-a292-a34b-e435-8795281ec393"
      }
   ]
```

I want to remove some tags in here and show only few tags.but I have know idea how to do this.can someone help me?

Comment: what are the tags you want to remove?

Comment: Where are your JS codes?

Comment: use delete keyword to delete some property from JSON object. i.e. `delete data.Actions[0].name`

Comment: @Sandeep funny how he wants to delete a `tag` but you show him how to delete a `name`

Comment: @Adelin I think it's not your call ?

Comment: using index I can't delete.because this array create dynamically. when i select element in drop down list.then this create...it retrive data from json file and show this array. in here two elements.but it can be changeaccording to your selection.

Comment: @maneesha5 delete property whenever your array completely created

Comment: can you explain how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete any element inside dynamically generated json array by following pattern

```js
var data = {
 "Actions":[  
      {  
         "key":"AC_001",
         "tag":"AWARD_POINTS",
         "name":"Award Points",
         "content":{  
            "html":"<div class='col-sm-4'><label for='point-amount'>Amount</label><input type='number' class='form-control' id='point-amount' placeholder='Add Points'></div>",
            "actions":""
         },
         "identify":"",
         "value":"",
         "uuid":"f0a8ae1f-9c2c-9cc3-eb38-7a7ab0570dd1"
      },
      {  
         "key":"AC_003",
         "tag":"SEND_MAIL",
         "name":"Send Mail",
         "content":{  
            "html":""
         },
         "identify":"",
         "value":"",
         "uuid":"83af6438-a292-a34b-e435-8795281ec393"
      }
   ]
}
 
for(var x=0; x<data.Actions.length; x++) 
{   
 var key = "tag";
 delete data.Actions[x][key];
 console.log(data.Actions[x].tag); //  should be undefined
    console.log(data.Actions[x].name); //  will be return value from array
}
```

Comment: thank you so much.It's working :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove some elements of the array and dont include them on your dropdown, you can use `filter`

Lets say you dont want to include the following array elements with tag

```
let doNotInclude = ['DELETE_THIS_TAG', 'TAG_TO_DELETE'];
```

You can use `filter` and `includes` to make a new array to use on your dropdown.

```js
let obj = {
  "Actions": [{
      "key": "AC_001",
      "tag": "AWARD_POINTS",
      "name": "Award Points",
      "content": {
        "html": "<div class='col-sm-4'><label for='point-amount'>Amount</label><input type='number' class='form-control' id='point-amount' placeholder='Add Points'></div>",
        "actions": ""
      },
      "identify": "",
      "value": "",
      "uuid": "f0a8ae1f-9c2c-9cc3-eb38-7a7ab0570dd1"
    },
    {
      "key": "AC_003",
      "tag": "DELETE_THIS_TAG",
      "name": "Delete",
      "content": {
        "html": ""
      },
      "identify": "",
      "value": "",
      "uuid": "83af6438-a292-a34b-e435-8795281ec393"
    },
    {
      "key": "AC_003",
      "tag": "SEND_MAIL",
      "name": "Send Mail",
      "content": {
        "html": ""
      },
      "identify": "",
      "value": "",
      "uuid": "83af6438-a292-a34b-e435-8795281ec393"
    },
    {
      "key": "AC_003",
      "tag": "TAG_TO_DELETE",
      "name": "Delete",
      "content": {
        "html": ""
      },
      "identify": "",
      "value": "",
      "uuid": "83af6438-a292-a34b-e435-8795281ec393"
    },
  ]
}

let doNotInclude = ['DELETE_THIS_TAG', 'TAG_TO_DELETE'];

let newObj = obj.Actions.filter(v => !doNotInclude.includes(v.tag));

console.log(newObj);
```